# array_count_values() with objects as values

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering, is there something similar to `array_count_values`, but that works with objects ?

Let me explain:

`array_count_values` takes an array as argument, such as

**[1]**

```
Array (
    [0] => banana
    [1] => trololol
)
```

If i give that array to `array_count_values`, i will get something like:

**[2]**

```
Array (
    [banana] => 1
    [trololol] => 1
)
```

Now lets say that instead of strings, i have objects, that i want to count based on one of their properties. So i have:

**[3]**

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [name] => banana
        [description] => banana, me gusta!
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [name] => trololol
        [description] => trolololololol
    )
)
```

And i'd want the magical-function-im-looking-for to count the number of objects with the same `name` property, returning the same input as **[2]**

Obviously i could easily do that on my own, but i was just wondering if there was a built-in function for that, since i couldnt seem to find one. Thanks, kind SOers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No such function exists. You always need to first map the values you would like to count (and those values must be string or integer):

```
$map = function($v) {return $v->name;};

$count = array_count_values(array_map($map, $data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 7.0, you can use `array_column` for this.

```
$counts = array_count_values(array_column($array_of_objects, 'name'));
```

When this question was originally asked and answered `array_column` didn't exist yet. It was introduced in PHP 5.5, but it couldn't handle arrays of objects until 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Reflection classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php) to easily fetch information about your objects dynamically.

Comment: The use of `ReflectionClass` is limited if you want to learn about properties of `stdClass` objects (as no properties are defined). Better use `ReflectionObject` or `get_object_vars()`.

Comment: i'll give a look at that, but @hakre's answer is just what i needed. Thanks though!